# EF, Code First, WCF => empty collection problem

Tags: c#, wcf, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I am having some problems with the Ef 4.1 code first implementation.

```
public class Foo()
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Bars = new Collection<Bar>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar()
{
    public Bar()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set;}
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

When I put a wcf service on top of this, it only returns an empty collection of Bars. If I turn on the ProxyCreationEnabled, the collection will be filled, but then I will get wcf exceptions and closed connections because of the EF proxy creation.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use eager loading if you want to load Bars as well. EF never loads related objects by itself. You must always ask EF for related objects either by eager loading or lazy loading. If you turn on proxy creation EF will try to load Bars collection by lazy loading during data serialization (first time the collection is accessed) but you will either get exception because of closed context or because of cycle in serialized data (`Bar.Foo` and `Foo.Bars` create cycle).

To use eager loading you must add `Include` method to your query:

```
var data = context.Foos.Include(f => f.Bars).ToList();
```

To avoid cycles you must either remove `Foo` in `Bar` or mark Foo and Bar with `DataContract` with `IsReference=true` and `DataMember` attributes:

```
[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Foo()
{
    public Foo()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        Bars = new Collection<Bar>();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection Bars { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference=true)]
public class Bar()
{
    public Bar()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set;}
}
```

Or you will have to mark `Foo` property in `Bar` as not serialized to break a cycle:

```
public class Bar()
{
    public Bar()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public virtual Foo Foo { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You say "EF never loads related objects by itself". Well, that cannot be true, as in the above example, if you turn on on ProxyCreationEnabled, the related objects are indeed loaded. I guess it is a feature of the Code First framework. That leads me to think that even though your solution might work, it is not the correct solution.

Comment: It is not feature of Code first. It is called lazy loading and again it doesn't trigger without by itself. It triggers once the navigation property is first accessed by the code you develop. In your case it will be serialization done by WCF service.

Comment: Monkeyboy 11, Ladislav 66k.  Needless to say Ladislav is quite correct.